# spring boot: run different init code for prod and tests

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am converting an existing Java application to Spring Boot.
I'm a Spring Boot newbie. I know Spring Boot has support for `application.properties`, which is great for new apps. But this is a legacy app and I need an interim solution for now - without completely redesigning it. This app needs to call some initializer with a property file on startup. There is `prod.properties` and another one for tests - `test.properties`.

the prod file needs to be loaded from a specific location on disk (/mydir/prod.properties), while `test.properties` comes from tests' classpath.
also, may legacy classes require this "property class" to be initialized on their creation (they reference it in their static initializers, oh geez...) - so this init needs to happen before Spring Components are loaded.

what would be the easiest solution?
I came up with this overly-verbose-boiler-plate solution. it works, but maybe there is an easier way?

```
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import javax.inject.Inject;
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Inject
    private Initializer initializer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        initializer.init();
    }
}

public interface Initializer {
    void init();
}

@Component
public class ProdInitializer implements Initializer {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("PROD init - will load properties file from /myfolder/ and call some init class with it");
    }
}

// and this is from TESTS section:

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Primary
@Component
public class TestInitializer implements Initializer {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("TEST init - will load properties file from classpath and call some init class with it");
    }
}
```

I tried having just one initializer with an additional  `test/resources/application.properties` file with just 1 value in it (legacy property file location) hoping that Spring Boot would load `application.properties` from PROD code, then load the only value present in `test/resources/application.properties` and override the corresponding value in `main/resources/application.properties`, but no luck - apparently, Spring Boot ignores `main/resources/application.properties` for tests if `test/resources/application.properties` is present. so I would have to duplicate all settings from `main/resources/application.properties` in `test/resources/application.properties` with just one property being different.

Comment: Are you using maven along? You can configure maven profile to read property specific environment property file.
Refer: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Why would you need to redesign your application? You would only need to rename your property files and use profiles. Put all default properties in `application.properties` then create an `application-prod.properties` and `application-test.properties`. Then for tests set the `spring.profiles.active` property to `test` and for `prod` otherwise. You can even use it in combination with `spring.config.location` to have your properties externalized. That should work without redesigning your application. You can then also add `@Profile("test")` to the beans only needed in test.